# How to integrate Mongodb Atlas with cloud integration platform such as mulesoft?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mulesoft, mongodb-stitch

So recently I started studying **MongoDB Atlas**. So just wanted to know how I can integrate that cloud database to any cloud integration tool such as **MULESOFT**. Do I have to create an API from **MongoDB Stitch** and then integrate it or am I missing something?
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The question is too wide in scope ('any cloud integration scope'). You should ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for [Mule Runtime](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/) (MuleSoft is the company name, not a product) you can use the [MongoDB connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/mongodb/mongodb-connector) to connect an application to a MongoDB database. For Atlas compatibility I have seen it is recommended to set the [authenticationDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41990738/721855) configuration.